# Facebook FQL query to get user's sent messages since a timestamp

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, message, inbox

I'm not too familiar with Facebook FQL. I'm looking for a way to see what users have received my message. I know I need to ask for extended permissions `read_mailbox`

For instance I would like to see if my message "hello" has been sent after 2013-05-02 14:00 and which recipient userIDs has it been sent to.

Input for the query would be the message "hello" and from timestamp "2013-05-02 14:00" to current timestamp.

Output from the query would be a list of userIDs that have been sent the message "hello" since the timestamp 2013-05-02 14:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found a solution:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:

@"{"
@"'query1':'SELECT thread_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN "
@"(SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 1 AND updated_time >= \"%.f\") "
@"AND author_id = me() and body = \"%@\","
@"'query2':'SELECT recipients, thread_id FROM thread WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM #query1)'"
@"}",

self.sendTime, self.facebookText];
```